# Implement Cloudinary Signed Upload in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, cloudinary

I am having a tough time in implementing signed upload to Cloudinary using Kotlin. I have implemented my backend to provide me a signture and timestamp. This is what I have done to build the config:

```
var config = HashMap<String, Any> ()
        config.put("cloud_name", "my_cloud_name");
        //config.put("apiKey", my_api_key);
        config.put("use_filename", true);
```

Now, I am unable to do the MediaManager.init using the signature. Can anyone please help? The Java code says to do the below, but I am unable to reproduce the same in Kotlin:

```
MediaManager.init(this, new SignatureProvider() {
    @Override
    public Signature provideSignature(Map options) {
        // call server signature endpoint
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: You should provide a first solution and the error you’re seeing

Answer (score 2):

This is how you intialize MediaManager with a signature provider in Kotlin:

```
MediaManager.init(thiscontext!!, object: SignatureProvider {
        override fun provideSignature(options: MutableMap<Any?, Any?>?): Signature {
            return myBackendConnector.signRequest(options)
        }

        override fun getName(): String {
            return "myCustomSignatureProvider"
        }

    }, config)
```

This will work assuming your backend already has the api key (it should), and that the return type from your connector is `Signature`. Otherwise you'll need to adapt your backend's result to `Signature` (populate the POJO with the result your server provided).

Comment: Still facing issues with this

Answer (score 0):

Get the `timestamp` and `signature` from your backend then add those as options.

```kotlin
val options = mapOf(
  "timestamp" to // timestamp from backend,
  "signature" to // signature from backend,
  // other options from backend
)
MediaManager.get()
            .upload(uri)
            .options(options)
            .callback(uploadCallback)
            .dispatch()
```

So this means not creating a `SignatureProvider` in the `MediaManager.init()`.

I came to using this because I could not get this to work with the `SignatureProvider` in the `MediaManager.init()`.